# Orchard CMS Disk Space

Tags: orchardcms, diskspace

Evening all,

I am playing with Orchard CMS and I have a quick question. I keep my source code on a 10GB partition on my PC; I downloaded the source for orchard (~40MB) and placed it on that drive.

Started visual studio, opened the solution and started a build, realised quite quickly that it was going to take some time so I went off and got a drink, came back to find it had errored out of the build and that the last 3GB of disk space on my dev drive had been filled. This can't be normal, can it?

Does anyone know how much free disk space I'll need to build orchard from the source? I am limited by the size of the SSD in my laptop and I'm not going to upgrade just so I can use orchard!

Comment: My entire orchard, with some custom modules, is around 2.5 gigs. But 10gigs is really not a lot for anything... storage is cheap as chips now

Comment: Yeah storage is cheap(ish) now... except Im on a laptop so it has to be external (slow) or I have to swap out my only hard drive...
Not only does the second option mean a reinstall of everything but really a sufficiently large SSD isn't cheap enough to justify just for a bit of a play around with orchard!

I have downloaded the pre-compiled site and am playing with the CMS front end now... if it is good enough to justify me looking into developing modules for it then I suppose Ill have to bite the bullet and buy that bigger SSD... 

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that vanilla source projects don't disable "copy local/private" for references. Therefore every project in the solution creates copies of all references in it's bin folders. This obviously isn't necessary here and increases size exponentially (since these references are shipped together anyway so better if they are included just once).

### You have 2 options:

1. **(Recommended)** Don't compile the source, I've been writing modules on top of precompiled version and never needed to make changes to the core source, that may do more harm than good. But if you really need to compile >
2. Force references to not copy locally, either manually for every single reference in every single project or find macro or maybe some VS magic to enforce it globally.